What zone should I assign the tunnel interface to?
In the Palo Alto document.
https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/network-security/ipsec-vpn/administration/set-up-site-to-site-vpn/set-up-ipsec/set-up-an-ipsec-tunnel
Network Security
Set Up an IPSec Tunnel (Tunnel Mode)
=====================================================================
Use your trust zone as the termination point for the tunnel—Select the zone. Associating the tunnel interface with the same zone (and virtual router) as the external-facing interface on which the packets enter the firewall mitigates the need to create inter-zone routing.
Or:
Create a separate zone for VPN tunnel termination (Recommended)—Select New Zone, define a Name for the new zone (for example vpn-corp), and click OK.
=====================================================================

So it means assign the tunnel interface to either a seperate VPN zone or Trust Zone. I understand that.
But what is "Associating the tunnel interface with the same zone (and virtual router) as the external-facing interface on which the packets enter the firewall mitigates the need to create inter-zone routing."
Isn't external-facing interface in untrust zone ? That is contradicting to what it just said "assign it to trust zone"

What I guess is there is actually 3 option here.

Use seperate VPN zone for tunnel interface (Recommended)
Use Trust Zone
Use Untrust Zone, which have a benefit of no need to create interzone routing


Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

The tunnel interface is a virtual link to the far-end network. Whatever your trust level for that network is, that's the trust level for the interface.
Most often you'd be running packets from/to various trust levels over a tunnel, so you might need to use a (new) mixed zone.
I'm not really familiar with PA, but on some firewalls you need to assign the highest level of trust that any firewall rule using it requires.
